# How to access .net functions/properties from AngularJS?

Tags: .net, vb.net, angularjs

We have a WinForm application hosting a web browser control. In this control a HTML page is displayed which contains AngularJS.

**Controller:**

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.CurrentDialog = window.external;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" content="yes">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="CurrentDialog.Text" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <h1>Hello {{CurrentDialog.Text}}!</h1>

    <span>{{CurrentDialog.Record.Item('Info')}}</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The input-field and the h1 works just fine, we can edit the Text-property from the WinForm without any problems.

But the statement in the span-element doesn't work. "Item" is a public function in our .NET code (class Record, it is set in the WinForm before displaying the HTML page) with a parameter. Without a parameter it works. What's wrong here?

**AngularJS code:**

```
{{CurrentDialog.Record.Item}} -> works, output: "Hello world!"
{{CurrentDialog.Record.Item('foobar')}} -> doesn't work, output: "undefined"
```

**VB.NET code:**

```
Public Function Item() As String
    Return "Hello world!"
End Function

Public Function Item(ByVal Field As String) As String
    Return "Hello world!"
End Function
```

Comment: Do Item['foobar'] works?

Comment: @Jamby: No, then there's no output.

Comment: Try double quotes around the foobar

Comment: @GruffBunny: Item["foobar"] -> no output, Item("foobar") -> "undefined".